# What does :<> (colon less-than greater-than) mean in ats

Tags: syntax, ats

Just met this symbol `:<>` in the dependently typed factorial section in the book "introduction to programming in ats": https://ats-lang.github.io/DOCUMENT/INT2PROGINATS/HTML/x3215.html
There seem to be no explanations before. My hypothesis is that it's the same as a single colon `:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This strange syntax is used to indicate that a function is pure, that is, causing no effects when is called.